# Docker daemon on Debian 7 returns "inappropriate ioctl for device"

Tags: debian, docker, ioctl

I just installed Docker on my Debian 7 system according to this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/installation/debian/#debian-wheezystable-7x-64-bit). When trying to start the Docker daemon via `docker -d`, I receive the following output:

```
INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)   
INFO[0000] WARNING: You are running linux kernel version 3.2.41-042stab094.7, which might be unstable running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.8.0. 
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock) 
INFO[0000] +job init_networkdriver()                    
inappropriate ioctl for device
INFO[0000] -job init_networkdriver() = ERR (1)          
FATA[0000] inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What is going on there and how can I fix it? I don't even have an idea what to look for.

Comment: The big WARNING text probably offers a clue ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Kernel version is 3.2 but Docker needs 3.8+. So you need to [upgrade](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel) your kernel version like it's pointed out in the guide you linked. After the  kernel upgrade you need to reboot your system and boot with the new kernel version. Now everything should work.